# What is the associated bundle of Hopf fibration?

Tags: fiber-bundles, hopf-fibration

I have learned that the Hopf fibration is a principal $S^1$-bundle over $S^2$. The $S^1$-action on $S^3\subseteq\mathbb{C}^2$ is given by
$$w\cdot(z_1,z_2)=(wz_1,wz_2).$$
Now let us consider the representation
$$\rho:S^1\to \text{Diff}(S^1), \quad w\mapsto \text{left multiplication by }w^n.$$
What is the associated bundle $E=S^3\times_{S^1}S^1$?

**My thought**: For $[z_1,z_2,w]\in E$, we have 
$$[z_1,z_2,w]=[z_1w^{1/n},z_2w^{1/n},1].$$
Does this mean that $E\cong S^{\color{red}3}$ as fibre bundle? If not, where am I wrong?

Comment: I think it's a Lens space. Probably $L(n,1)$.

Comment: I think so, but I get confused. How can I prove it?

Comment: Oh, I get it.  $[z_1,z_2,1]$ and $[z_1e^{2\pi i/n},z_2e^{2\pi i/n},1]$ are the same point.

Comment: Yeah, that's it.